# How to interpret predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm learning Employee Turnover Forecast and I got the result as below from predict_proba
If I see the first row, I may interpret as this employee would left the company by 83%.
Do I understand this correctly?

```
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
array([[0.17, 0.83],
       [0.43, 0.57],
       [0.29, 0.71],
       [0.94, 0.06],
       [0.98, 0.02],
       [0.84, 0.16],
       [0.64, 0.36],
       [1.  , 0.  ],
       [0.85, 0.15],
       [0.99, 0.01],
       [0.09, 0.91],
       [0.89, 0.11],
       [0.21, 0.79],
       [0.15, 0.85],
       [0.78, 0.22],
       [0.18, 0.82],
       [0.84, 0.16],
       [0.45, 0.55],
       [0.96, 0.04],
       [0.95, 0.05],
       [0.91, 0.09],
       [0.9 , 0.1 ],
       [1.  , 0.  ],
       [0.91, 0.09],
       [0.74, 0.26],
...
       [0.94, 0.06],
       [0.99, 0.01],
       [0.22, 0.78],
       [0.89, 0.11],
       [0.98, 0.02]])
```

Comment: Technically, it says that 83% of your trees (of your Random Forest) predicted that this employee would leave the company. Then, you can translate that to: "this employee has 83% probability to leave the company. PD: I'm assuming that the second values refers to the probability to leave company as you explained in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model score is a measure of the model certainty of the outcome. However, it's not necessarily the same as probability: it does not mean 83% people with 0.83 score leaving yet. Logistic regression scores are probabilities by design, but for random forest behaviour is implementation defined. If you seek to integrate your scores into business metrics directly, you'll need to calibrate your model first (using e.g. `sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV` or isotonic regression).

Comment: Really appreciate for your kind advice!